# Does GFCI ONLY affect connected receptacles and is GFCI ONLY affected by adjoining receptacles

Tags: gfci

We had our GFCI fault yesterday afternoon,we thought it was the GFCI since we replaced it yrs ago and they do go bad sometimes. We bought a new one, put it in same wiring as the previous and it did not work. We checked the adjoining receptacles that were part of that circuit to the GFCI. GFCI is in master bath, affects light switch, hall bathroom wall receptacles  and outside carport receptacle. Checked them all, replaced receptacles just to be sure. Still nothing. The line shows power but not load. We checked wires for hot, etc. We even switched out breaker box breaker. The breaker switch also controls some other receptacles  & lights. Now we find two of the wall receptacles that are not part of the GFCI are not working.
Note: We did have huge rain yesterday, thought it may be moisture driven but found no evidence. Even went to attic to check, nothing.
Any ideas???? We are totally stumped.

Comment: When you say "it's not working" does that mean no power or it keeps tripping?

Comment: You are throwing parts at this without doing a proper diagnosis. Breakers very seldom fail. A simple volt meter test would have told you if the breaker was OK or not.

Comment: sorry for grammar.  no power on the gfci, it cant trip cause it has no power on the load. the line has power by the tester. We're heading to lowes for better tester. No receptacles in line have any power.

Comment: The breaker was fine, he just wanted to change it since its old. sorry that i'm not great at typing. just trying to help him out. its not tripping because it wont reset at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll see what we find with new tester. Hopefully it will help pin point something so we know where to focus.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that you can't reset the breaker? (In other words, when you flip the switch does it immediately click and flip to the middle?) If so, you have a wiring short.

Comment: @Becka  Regarding grammar, absolutely no worries, we all make mistakes at times and this is a pretty serious site, so many times a question or answer will get edited to make it higher quality and more useful.        .....I do mistaks too becase i whent two publik skools!  (SIC)

Comment: You have a problem (wet) somewhere but you have not found it yet. The GFCI will detect unbalance between Line and Load.

Comment: Do you need that GFCI to protect loads in those other places? For that matter did you even know that GFCI was protecting loads in other places? Are you OK with them NOT having GFCI protection and/or giving each of those sockets their own GFCI?

Comment: tester indicates, per lights, hot & ground reversed on the GFCI and another receptacle. i was thinking it was a water problem just because it happened to be just after the rain, probably coincidence but we found nothing. i'll read up to see what we need to do about the tester results.

Comment: we did get a tester, the tester initially said hot& ground reversed. We kept researching and while doing that after we tested other receptacles and found mixed results, some reversed, others not affected as correct, Magically the GFCI functioned BUT the rains stopped and some drying so we are pretty sure it is from moisture. The reading on the meter simple was wrong response but also right that there was an issue. All is good on all parts other than we MUST find where the moisture is getting to these receptacles so we'll keep looking.  THank again for all the responses and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GFCI/receptacle has two sets of screw connections - **line** and **load**.

Any time you have  problem, the first step is to disconnect the *load* wires. With load disconnected, the *only* things that matter are:

- The GFCI/receptacle itself. These can go bad. They can also get water in them which can cause intermittent trips (or failure to reset) until they are totally dried out - that is *by design*.
- No incoming power - e.g., hot or neutral not connected properly to the *line* side.

So if with *load* disconnected you still can't get the GFCI to reset, check voltage between the incoming hot & neutral wires. If it is ~ 120V and the connections are solid then you likely have a bad GFCI/receptacle. If you don't have ~ 120V then the problem is at the breaker or someplace between the breaker and the GFCI/receptacle.

If replacing the GFCI/receptacle does not solve the problem then *temporarily* install a regular, non-GFCI, receptacle. If that works then there is something wacky going on. If that doesn't work then the problem is in the breaker or the wiring between the breaker and the receptacle.

If you either get a good result when *load* is disconnected or you replace the GFCI/receptacle and it works, double-check for 120V on the *load* connections and, assuming that shows ~ 120V, *then* you reconnect the load wires. If everything works, great. If you get an immediate trip then one of the receptacles or other devices connected via *load* has a ground fault. If you don't get an immediate trip but you get a trip when you plug in and/or turn on a particular device then that is the source of your problem.

Comment: thanks, tester indicates "hot & ground reversed"?

Comment: That's the wrong tester here. That's a 3-light tester (what Harper calls a Magic 8-Ball). It is very useful for some things. It is not what you need here. What "hot & ground reverse" means *if there is nothing really wacky going on* is a reasonable voltage between hot & neutral (good) and also a reasonable voltage between neutral & ground (not good). Which is possibly hot & ground reverse, but that is a rare combination to see.

Comment: What you need here is a multimeter. Then you can check the line side wires connected (should show ~120V). And disconnected (hanging carefully in mid-air - turn off breaker, disconnect the wires and separate widely from each other from ground and from metal box, turn on breaker, check voltage, turn off breaker, reconnect). Should be black to hot, white to neutral, if bare or green wire present that connects to ground - all connections on GFCI should be pretty clear. Nothing to load (which should initially have come with tape covering the load hot & neutral screws).

Comment: ok, you're right the tester is wrong. While trying to figure this out, the gfci is working and we didnt do anything yet but check the receptacles with the tester BUT it has stopped raining and drying up so i believe the tester results does not indicate a reversal but rather i suspect the dampness or moisture affecting the GFCI and gives this reading.

Comment: Dampness *will* trip a GFCI. It should not cause that type of anomalous 3-light reading without *also* tripping the GFCI.

Comment: we checked the receptacles again after the GFCI reset and is functioning and all are working and TESTING correctly now as is the GFCI. We did test and reset checking the receptacles response to test and all worked perfectly. NOW we just have to figure out how& where moisture is getting to the GFCI or its joined receptacles. Whew !! THANKS to all for responses and offers of help.

Comment: THANK YOU so much for taking the time out of your day to respond to our crisis and help in troubleshooting to resolve.  THANK YOU

Comment: The proper way to say "thank you", @Becka, is to click the up-vote arrow next to any answer that helps you and to click the check-mark for the one that helped the most. This also helps others to know that the issue has a solution - good for those who are looking to answer questions so they don't need to spend time answering one that has already been resolved for the OP, and good for others with a similar problem to know that a question has a resolution that worked for someone else.